# Pagination for fetching total records

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pagination, request, fetch

I want to fix a bug in pagination I am getting records as 1-10 of 10 items or 1-20 of 20 items while it is having 180 records in total so I want to show results as 1-10 of 180

Note:when I am clicking submit button I am getting expected results

I tried to fix in controller like
Objgroup.page = 1

Objgroup.pagesize = 10

request.page = 1

Comment: Can you provide the code so that it will help me out to check